# user Data are not showing in label

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display the user data in screen. But I always get an empty value. I don't know why.

```
var profileData = Profile(usrObj: [String:String]())

@IBOutlet weak var userName: UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    self.userName.text = profileData.FirstName
    print(profileData.FirstName)
}
```

My print statement and my label value are empty. Please help me out with any mistake I am making.

**My model class :**

```
class Profile {
    var FirstName: String

    init(usrObj : [String: AnyObject]) {
        self.FirstName = (usrObj["FirstName"] ?? "") as! String
    }

    var ProfileObject: [String:AnyObject] {
        return ["FirstName" : self.FirstName]
    }
```

Comment: Where do you set the `FirstName` property of `profileData` to a non-empty value?

Comment: That only i was not able to understand how to set. ??

Comment: If you never set `FirstName` to a specific value, then why are you surprised that you are getting an empty value?

Comment: I have updated my model class of profileData ..

Comment: I have set the `FirstName ` to my label.text. Or if i  am wrong. How can i assign as a property ??

Comment: @mack check my answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your  `LoginViewController` save your data in NSUserDefaults

```
@IBAction func loginWithUserNamePassword(){
     KRProgressHUD.show(progressHUDStyle: .White, message: "Loading...")
    loginWithMailAndPassword((username.text?.trimWhiteSpace)!, password: (password.text?.trimWhiteSpace)!) { (user, error) in
     if error != nil{
           KRProgressHUD.dismiss()
           SCLAlertView().showError("Login Error", subTitle: error!.localizedDescription)
      }
      else {
          if user!.emailVerified
          {
                currentUser = user

                fireBaseRef.child("Users").child(currentUser!.uid).child("UserProfile").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
                     if let data: [String : AnyObject] = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject] {
                           let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
                            userDefaults.setObject(data, forKey: "userdata")
                            userDefaults.synchronize()
                            enableSync()
                            self.navigateToNextScreen()
                        }
                        else{

                        }
                    })
            }
            else
            {
                SCLAlertView().showError("Login Error", subTitle: "This email is has not been verified yet")
            }
        }
      }
  }
```

and use that data in `UserStaticDataViewController`

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
         self.profileDetailsExists = true

        let userdata : NSDictionary = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().valueForKey("userdata") as! NSDictionary

        print(userdata["City"] as? String)
         self.userName.text = userdata["FirstName"] as? String
        self.userCity!.text = userdata["City"] as? String
        self.userCountry!.text = userdata.valueForKey("Country") as? String
        self.userState.text = userdata.valueForKey("State") as? String
        self.userMobileNo.text = userdata.valueForKey("Mobile") as? String

        self.userGmail.text = userdata.valueForKey("Email") as? String
        self.userDob.text = userdata.valueForKey("DateOfBirth") as? String


    }
```

**Output:**

[image: Check]

**Just approve my answer and give vote.
Happy coding.**

Comment: that is static data screen design dude

Comment: then when i call some api for get some data.

Comment: @mack check now

Answer (score 0):

From the fact that your print statement is empty, it means that the userObject you pass into the following equation

```
var profileData = Profile(usrObj: [String:String]())
```

probably does not have a string value for the key "firstName".

You can try to verify this by changing your code

```
self.FirstName = (usrObj["FirstName"] ?? "") as! String
```

to

```
self.FirstName = (usrObj["FirstName"] ?? "Hello world") as! String
```

and see if "Hello world" is printed out in your console.

If yes, then you just have to make sure that the "user" object you pass into the init function of Profile class should be a dictionary where a value is stored for the key "FirstName"